# How to use Binary Jedis in version 4.3.2?

Tags: java, jedis

In Jedis version 2.8.0 I have used **redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis**

What should I use to save binary key value pairs using Jedis Client 4.3.2?
Can someone point me towards documentation or provide a sample snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Jedis` class. It has support for all the binary variants.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can share an example.
I am doing this  `jedis.set(uuid.getBytes(), value);` for now. 
And have referred https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/redis-as-object-storage-e6a084b46f8b

Comment: `jedis.set(uuid.getBytes(), value);` seems to be valid method call. Let us know what's not working in your code.